# How to create an MSIX pckage from source with self-contained=false

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msix

The project (netcore3.1) is being packaged with a Windows Application Packaging Project (.wapproj + .appxmanifest) and published for sideloading using:

right click packaging project->Publish->Create App Packages

The error is:
"It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier, Please either specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false."

Other answers describe workarounds and methods to get the publishing system to recognise a RuntimeIdentifier, but none explains how to disable self-contained packaging. Surely there is a flag or property that can be set to create a package without the runtime libraries.

Comment: Did you made any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with **SelfContained=True** or **DesktopBridgeSelfContained** params of your *.wapproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WpfApp1\WpfApp.csproj">
      <DesktopBridgeSelfContained>False</DesktopBridgeSelfContained>
      <DesktopBridgeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86</DesktopBridgeIdentifiers>
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
      <Properties>SelfContained=True;RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64;PublishReadyToRun=true</Properties>
      <SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>True</SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I have the problem too and tried your suggestions without success. I would be pleased if you could clone my super minimal example, which has a working msix generation configured, and adjust it to create a msix file without a .net framework. Aka “SelfContained=False“. Check it out here: https://github.com/juwens/WpfNet5Msix